# Scaling tabular row spacing down for tiny font size

Tags: tables, spacing, fontsize

I have a `tabular` environment in which all the cells of some rows are `\tiny`; a minimal example:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
Dexterity \\ \hline
\tiny Saving Throws: $+2$ \\
\tiny Acrobatics: $+4$ \\
\tiny Sleight of Hand: $+2$ \\
\tiny Stealth: $+6$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

The problem with the above is that there's too much vertical space between the tiny-sized rows; ideally, the interrow spacing should be scaled down proportionally to the `\tiny` size.  However, I don't know how to do that.  My best attempt was to try to store the tiny-sized baseline skip with `{\tiny\setlength\tinybls{\baselineskip}}` (after inserting `\newlength\tinybls` in the preamble) and then append `[\tinybls]` to each `\\`, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: In my opinion, you should not use the  \tiny font size – no one will read your table. The lower limit, I think? is \ footnotesize.

Comment: The space needs to be negative, e.g., `\\[-5pt]`.

Comment: @Bernard: This is solely for my own consumption, and if I use a larger size, the table in question overflows too much.

Comment: You may have multiline cells to prevent overflowing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the sub-properties in its own `tabular` after choosing the appropriate font size :

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | }
  \hline
  Dexterity \\ % Property
  \hline
  \tiny % Font size of sub-properties
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} r @{: } l @{} }
      Saving Throws & $+2$ \\
         Acrobatics & $+4$ \\
    Sleight of Hand & $+2$ \\
            Stealth & $+6$
  \end{tabular} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Better yet, define a command that would set this for you. It will allow you to change things later on with much less hassle and more consistency... we all like the latter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\propertycard}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | }
    \hline
    #1 \\ % Property
    \hline
    \tiny % Sub-property font style
    \begin{tabular}{ @{} r @{: } l @{} }
      #2 % Sub-properties
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\propertycard{Dexterity}{%
    Saving Throws & $+2$ \\
       Acrobatics & $+4$ \\
  Sleight of Hand & $+2$ \\
          Stealth & $+6$
}

\end{document}
```